# Uniform convergence, Bounded derivative.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n(x):[0,1] \to \Bbb R$ be a sequence of differentiable functions such that for every $n$ and every $x \in [0,1]$ we have $|f'_n(x)| \leq 1$. Also, $f_n \to f$ (pointwise convergence) in $[0,1]$. Prove that $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly.

I managed to prove that for every $x_0$, there is a uniform convergence in $(x_0-\delta, x_0 +\delta)$ for some $\delta > 0$.

How can I finish the proof?

Comment: Well, how does your proof go? (Without that, it's hard to say how to build from it to get the more general statement).

Comment: I used that fact that $f$ is uniformly continuous

Comment: Please, provide the details of your argument. The above gives little to none. Also, what tools are you allowed to use? Do you know the dominated convergence theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can end your proof like this: since $[0,1]$ is compact, you can find $x_1,...,x_n$ and $a_1>0,...,a_n>0$ such that $f_n$ converges uniformly of $(x_i-a_i,x_i+a_i)$ and $\bigcup_i(x_i-a_i,x_i+a_i)\cap [0,1]=[0,1]$.

For every $c>0$, there exists $N_i$ such that for every $n>N_i, x\in (x_i-a_i,x_i+a_i)$ implies that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<c$. Take $n=Sup(N_1,...,N_n)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that
$$f_n(x)=f_n(0)+\int_{0}^xf_n'(t)\,dt$$
Then
$$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leq |f_n(0)-f_m(0)|+\int_{0}^1|f_n'(t)-f'_m(t)|\,dt$$
Now by using the pointwise convergence and [dominated convergence theorem](http://Dominated%20convergence%20theorem) show that $(f_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $C([0,1])$ with the sup norm.

Comment: I am not sure if the OP is aware of Dominated Convergence Theorem

Comment: Yes, I havn't learned this thorem...

Comment: @user401516 I am sorry to hear that. In hope that the other answers will be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since you managed to prove that for every $x_0 \in [0,1]$, there exists a $\delta \gt 0$ such that for all $x \in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$, $f_n \to f$ uniformly and $[0,1] \subset \cup_{x_0 \in [0,1]}(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$, use the compactness of $[0,1]$ to extract a finite subcover